# Can Tomcat be configured to fail to start if a webapp fails to start?

Tags: tomcat, startup

I'd like to configure Tomcat 5.5 to fail to start if any of its webapps fail to start. Is that possible? I can't find any configuration element in the documentation that suggestions that this can be done.

Comment: That's a great question.  Try http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html#tomcat-users and come back here if you get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no security manager running, you can simply call `System.exit(0)` on failure. The shutdown handler will perform an orderly shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's no way to do it with a configuration setting.  Tomcat is started with a script.  Extend the script to check whether your site is up, and then stop tomcat if it isn't.